# Schedule expiration in node-postgres

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

In node, i want to schedule removal of expired email validation tokens. I have [found](https://www.codementor.io/@audax_gh/how-to-implement-email-verification-feature-in-your-nodejs-app-using-express-sendgrid-sequelize-orm-mysql-mb4x23etv) a working MySQL-statement, but it is not compatible with postgres.

```
CREATE EVENT expireToken
        ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL  1 DAY 
        DO
        DELETE FROM verification_tokens WHERE createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

How could i solve the same problem using node and node-postgres?

Answer (score 0):

PostgresSQL does not support time-based triggers.  If you want to execute SQL on a regular schedule you can create a function and execute it from a `cron` job.

Alternatively, [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/getting_started.html) offers a convenient web-based interface to acheive the same.